# How can I trigger multiple asynchronous calls that utilize a third party node module within Meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, meteor

I am working on an admin UI using Meteor js (my first Meteor project) and have a bit of a situation. I've got a js class, which uses an asynchronous call from a 3rd party module, then uses the results of that call to trigger multiple calls to another 3rd party api. Since the second "round" of calls might be 10-20 calls, I'd like to run them in parallel, collect the results, then return them to meteor. Problem is, Meteor keeps crashing with exit code 8 whenever the "second" round of calls are triggered.

Here's a rough flow (outline) of what's happening:

1. Meteor calls an Async wrapped method to in the class I wrote.
2. Internal to class I wrote, a third party API is called (rest API) and results are gotten in a callback (in the class).
3. In that callback, I iterate the results of API 1, and create separate instances of objects of API 2, one to make each request.
4. As soon as (or soon after) triggering the first call to API 2, Meteor crashes with exit code 8.

The console flashes a message, quickly, sometimes, but I can't read it (and can't find where meteor saves crash logs).

Any thoughts, welcome. Ultimately, I may pull all this code *out* of meteor, and behind a node rest api of my own, but I'd like to be able to develop/test it as a class used by Meteor directly.

Comment: And what is your code? You should use Meteor call callbacks, like Meteor.call('test',function(err,result){if(!err) Meteor.call('test2',function(..., and use reactive vars which will contain data, since calls are asynchronous

Comment: Have you tried to run your app with "meteor debug" ?

Comment: @Molda  - thanks for the response. In the end, I figured it out. The structure I had actually worked fine, the difficulty was that bad code in the second layer of async api calls caused a crash. What I learned was that running in debug/collecting log to file is the way to solve the mysterious crash.